# MySQL and InnoDB - UPDATE with WHERE on non unique index - how are rows encountered?

Tags: mysql, innodb

How are the rules in context of table row encountering when UPDATE with WHERE is performed on non-unique indexed column ?

I have a test table with col column as non-unique index:

```
id  |  col
----------
1   |  1
----------
2   |  2
----------
3   |  2
----------
22  |  3


UPDATE tab SET col=1 WHERE col=1;
// OR
UPDATE tab SET col=3 WHERE col=3;
// OR
UPDATE tab SET col=2 WHERE col=2;     
// These updates encounter ONLY rows where col=1, col=3 or col=2
```

Same table and same updates, but with one more record in the table where col=2:

```
id  |  col
----------
1   |  1
----------
2   |  2
----------
3   |  2
----------
4   |  2
----------
22  |  3


UPDATE tab SET col=1 WHERE col=1;
// OR
UPDATE tab SET col=3 WHERE col=3;
// Both updates encounter ONLY rows where col=1 or col=3.

UPDATE tab SET col=2 WHERE col=2;     
// This update encounters ALL the rows in the table even those where col IS NOT 2.
// WHY ?
```

Comment: how would you know if its scanning full table?

Comment: Because it sets a lock on all rows. If I use "UPDATE tab SET col=2 WHERE col=2" in open transaction and then in session2 I try "UPDATE tab SET col=1 WHERE id=1" or "UPDATE tab SET col=3 WHERE id=22", both updates in session2 wait for lock release. (btw id column is PK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, every row encountered in the processing of an `UPDATE` is exclusively row-locked. This means that the locking impact of an `UPDATE` depends on how the query is processed to read the rows to be updated. If your `UPDATE` query uses no index, or a bad index, it may lock many or all rows. (Note that the *order* in which rows are locked also depends on the index used.) In your case, since your table is very small and you're materially changing the distribution of the rows in your index, it is choosing to use a full table scan for the query in question.

You can test the performance and behavior of most `UPDATE` queries by converting them to a `SELECT` and using `EXPLAIN SELECT` on them (in newer versions you can even `EXPLAIN UPDATE`).

In short, though: You should have tables with a realistic distribution of data bInefore testing performance or locking behavior, not a very small table with a few test rows.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you very much for the answer ! You wrote - "In your case, since your table is very small and you're materially changing the distribution of the rows in your index, it is choosing to use a full table scan for the query in question."... If no index was used for search in this queries: UPDATE tab SET col=1 WHERE col=1; or UPDATE tab SET col=3 WHERE col=3; then I don't understand why locks are set only on rows where col=1 or col=3 and not to whole table as It should be a full table scan. Thanks.

Comment: @DusanCani You can verify with `EXPLAIN`, but I would expect that it *is* using the index for the `col=1` and `col=3` cases. The index usage decisions depend somewhat on the estimated number of rows matched. (Note that with tables this small, those estimates can be wildly incorrect though.)

Comment: Could I understand in a simply way how the InnoDB index is traversed while searching a value ? For a simplified example, let's assume that I have non-unique index column with these values: 2,2,3,4,8,11,11,25,29,30,31. I use some statement with WHERE, for example UPDATE tab SET col = 8 WHERE col=8. Which records are encountered before search finds all records where col=8 ? I studied your articles about InnoDB but I found it too complex to understand how index is traversed while search. Maybe this process is too complicated and It cannot be understood easily :( Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: @DusanCani Only the row with col=8 will be locked. I think part of the challenge to understand this is to understand that only the rows which are returned from InnoDB to MySQL are locked. In case of an index scan which uses a good index, this is exactly what you expect. In case no good index can be used, many rows are returned from InnoDB to MySQL, and MySQL will filter them based on the `WHERE` conditions. In that case all rows are locked whether they ended up matching the filter or not.

Comment: According to this schema: http://jcole.us/blog/files/innodb/20130109/72dpi/B_Tree_Structure.png If searched column value is for example 3 than index record with column value of 2 needs to be compared if it equals 3 as it is stored on the same leaf page (7) so it's also encountered while search and should be also locked. Do I understand it correctly or does it work differently ? Thanks.

Comment: @DusanCani Not exactly, the row is only locked if it is *returned* from InnoDB to MySQL, and in this case any record comparisons which would be made would happen inside InnoDB. It might compare record 2, but it also may not, for instance if the page directory contained a pointer to exactly the right record (see: http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/14/efficiently-traversing-innodb-btrees-with-the-page-directory/). One interesting exception to this is if the record doesn't exist at all, since only existing records can be record-locked, to "lock" a non-existent record requires locking its neighbors.

Comment: My last question: So is it possible that InnoDB might return to MySQL all rows instead of specific expected rows although the index was used ? Consider the second table mentioned at beginning of this topic. If I use "UPDATE tab SET col=2 WHERE col=2" it locks all rows in this table. But "EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col=2" shows "Using index".

Comment: @DusanCani "Using index" doesn't mean what you think it means. What is `type` in your `EXPLAIN` output? I would guess `index`, which means a full index scan (similar to a full table scan, but reads all rows from the index, rather than all rows from the table [which for InnoDB would mean `PRIMARY KEY`]).

Comment: the "type" in my explain output is "ref"

Comment: Are you sure that EXPLAIN for SELECT with using WHERE is the same result as for UPDATE with WHERE ? I could use EXPLAIN for UPDATE statement, but this is available only in MySQL 5.6 and higher but I am runnig on 5.5 now.I should upgrade.

Comment: @DusanCani Well, they are certainly not guaranteed to make the same decisions, so no, `EXPLAIN SELECT` isn't always indicative of what `UPDATE` would do...

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful article out there.I believe this would answer your queries.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/